# MVC C# Dropdown list Showing System.Web.SelectListItem on the model and can not blind to controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Please help me. My dropdownlist showing `System.Web.SelectListItem` in debug mode but not showing actual text that I defined in the list. Can anyone please help. How make the controller to have the text that I define in the list. Also my dropdownlist is not blinding in selecting. Please help me

[This is how it look like, please take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOjsc.png)

Here the my model:

```
public List<SelectListItem> KeywordOptions { get; set; }
public int KeywordOptionsSelected { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> MarketandRevenueOptions { get; set; }
public int MarketandRevenueOptionsSelected { get; set; }
    
public List<SelectListItem> KeywordsList { get; set; }
public int KeywordsListSelected { get; set; }
```

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult WACCtest(string RegionID1, bool HongKong = false, bool China = false, bool marketmultiples = false, bool dcf = false)
{
    var objWACC = new WACC();

    XmlDocument xmlTmp = webS.GetWaccOptionsIndustries();
    objWACC.Industries = new List<Industry>();

    XmlDocument nodeCompsTmp = webS._Test_CompsFilter();
    objWACC.Companies = new List<ComparableCompanies>();

    XmlDocument nodeMktRevenueTmp = webS._Test_MktCapRevenue();
    objWACC.MrkCapRevenue = new List<MrkCapAndRevenue>();

    XmlNodeList nodeListMktCap1 = nodeMktRevenueTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Mkt_Cap");
    XmlNodeList nodeListRevenue = nodeMktRevenueTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Revenue");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeListMktCap1.Count; i++)
    {
        MrkCapAndRevenue objMktCapRevenue = new MrkCapAndRevenue();
        objMktCapRevenue.Mrk_Cap = double.Parse(nodeListMktCap1[i].InnerText.Trim());
        objMktCapRevenue.Revenue = nodeListRevenue[i].InnerText.Trim();

        objWACC.MrkCapRevenue.Add(objMktCapRevenue);
    }

    XmlNodeList nodeListCompID = nodeCompsTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Company_ID");
    XmlNodeList nodeListCompName = nodeCompsTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Company_Name");
    XmlNodeList nodeListStockTicker = nodeCompsTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Stock_Ticker");
    XmlNodeList nodeListIPO = nodeCompsTmp.GetElementsByTagName("IPO_Date");
    XmlNodeList nodeListCompWeb = nodeCompsTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Company_Website");
    XmlNodeList nodeListCompDescr = nodeCompsTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Company_Description");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeListCompID.Count; i++)
    {
        ComparableCompanies objComparableComps = new ComparableCompanies();
        objComparableComps.Company_ID = int.Parse(nodeListCompID[i].InnerText.Trim());
        objComparableComps.Company_Name = nodeListCompName[i].InnerText.Trim();
        objComparableComps.Stock_Ticker = nodeListStockTicker[i].InnerText.Trim();
        objComparableComps.IPO_Date = DateTime.Parse(nodeListIPO[i].InnerText.Trim());
        objComparableComps.Company_Website = nodeListCompWeb[i].InnerText.Trim();
        objComparableComps.Company_Description = nodeListCompDescr[i].InnerText.Trim();

        objWACC.Companies.Add(objComparableComps);
    }

    //EC: add the columns one by one
    XmlNodeList nodeListGICCode = xmlTmp.GetElementsByTagName("GIC_Code");
    XmlNodeList nodeListIndName = xmlTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Industry_Name");
    XmlNodeList nodeListIndLvl = xmlTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Industry_Level");
    XmlNodeList nodeListParentGICCode = xmlTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Parent_GIC_Code");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeListGICCode.Count; i++)
    {
        Industry indTemp = new Industry();
        indTemp.GIC_Code = int.Parse(nodeListGICCode[i].InnerText.Trim());
        indTemp.Industry_Name = nodeListIndName[i].InnerText.Trim();
        indTemp.Industry_Level = int.Parse(nodeListIndLvl[i].InnerText.Trim());
        indTemp.Parent_GIC_Code = 0;

        if (indTemp.Industry_Level != 1)
        { 
            indTemp.Parent_GIC_Code = int.Parse(nodeListParentGICCode[i].InnerText.Trim()); 
        }  //EC: no need to check the parent if industry level = 1 since it has no parent (will result an exception for level 1)

        objWACC.Industries.Add(indTemp);
    }

    string strValDate = Request.QueryString["ValuationDate"] ?? "2020-01-01";
    string strIndustrySelected = Request.QueryString["IndustrySelected"] ?? "0";     // BW: the selected varaables are based on index value
    string strLocationSelected = Request.QueryString["LocationSelected"] ?? "1";
    string strFV = Request.QueryString["FairValue"] ?? "0.0";
    string strRFR = Request.QueryString["RiskFreeRate"] ?? "0.0";
    string strBETA = Request.QueryString["Beta"] ?? "0.0";
    string strMRPs = Request.QueryString["Mrp"] ?? "0.0";
    string strCAPM = Request.QueryString["CAPM"] ?? "0.0";
    string strTAXRATE = Request.QueryString["TaxRate"] ?? "0.0";
    string strLendingRate = Request.QueryString["LendingRate"] ?? "0.0";
    string strWE = Request.QueryString["WE"] ?? "0.0";
    string strWD = Request.QueryString["WD"] ?? "0.0";
    string strAFTaxCod = Request.QueryString["AFTaxCod"] ?? "0.0";

    string strBetaSelected = Request.QueryString["BetaSelected"] ?? "0";
    string strMrpSelected = Request.QueryString["MrpSelected"] ?? "0";

    string strSizePr = Request.QueryString["SizePremium"] ?? "0.0";
    string strCompSpecPr = Request.QueryString["ComSpecPr"] ?? "0.0";
    string strLendRatePr = Request.QueryString["LendRatePr"] ?? "0.0";

    string strOtherPr = Request.QueryString["OtherPr"] ?? "0.0";

    string strIndustries = Request.QueryString["Industries"] ?? "0";

    string strKeywordOptions = Request.QueryString["KeywordOptions"] ?? "0";

    string strKeywordsSelected = Request.QueryString["KeywordOptionsSelected"] ?? "TEST 2";

    string strMarketandRevenueOptionsSelected = Request.QueryString["MarketandRevenueOptionsSelected"] ?? "0";

    string strKeywordsListSelected = Request.QueryString["KeywordsListSelected"] ?? "0";

    //BW: Define variable as double integer for the selecting Values
    int intIndSel = 0;
    int intLocSel = 0;
    double dblFV = 0.0;
    double dblRFR = 0.0;
    double dblBeta = 0.0;
    double dblMRP = 0.0;
    double dblCAPM = 0.0;
    double dblTAXRATE = 0.0;
    double dblLendingRate = 0.0;
            double dblWE = 0.0;
            double dblWD = 0.0;
            double dblAFTaxCod = 0.0;
            int intBetSel = 0;
            int intMrpSel = 0;
            string[] strVD = new string[3];
            DateTime dtVD = new DateTime(2020, 01, 01);
            List<string> listIndustry = new List<string>();

            int intKeywordsSel = 0;

            int intMarketandRevenueOptionsSel = 0;

            int intKeywordsListSel = 0;

     
      
            double dblSP = 0.0;
            double dblCSP = 0.0;
            double dblLRP = 0.0;
            double dblOPR = 0.0;

            try { intIndSel = int.Parse(strIndustrySelected); } catch { intIndSel = 0; } //EC: add 1 to take into account of the default item 
            try { intLocSel = int.Parse(strLocationSelected); } catch { intLocSel = 0; }
            try { dblFV = double.Parse(strFV); } catch { dblFV = 0.0; }
            try { dblRFR = double.Parse(strRFR); } catch { dblRFR = 0.0; }
            try { dblBeta = double.Parse(strBETA); } catch { dblBeta = 0.0; }
            try { dblMRP = double.Parse(strMRPs); } catch { dblMRP = 0.0; }
            try { dblCAPM = double.Parse(strCAPM); } catch { dblCAPM = 0.0; }
            try { dblTAXRATE = double.Parse(strTAXRATE); } catch { dblTAXRATE = 0.0; }
            try { dblLendingRate = double.Parse(strLendingRate); } catch { dblLendingRate = 0.0; }
            try { dblWE = double.Parse(strWE); } catch { dblWE = 0.0; }
            try { dblWD = double.Parse(strWD); } catch { dblWD = 0.0; }
            try { dblAFTaxCod = double.Parse(strAFTaxCod); } catch { dblWD = 0.0; }
            try { intBetSel = int.Parse(strBetaSelected); } catch { intBetSel = 0; }
            try { intMrpSel = int.Parse(strMrpSelected); } catch { intMrpSel = 0; }
            try { dblSP = double.Parse(strSizePr); } catch { dblSP = 0.0; }
            try { dblCSP = double.Parse(strCompSpecPr); } catch { dblCSP = 0.0; }
            try { dblLRP = double.Parse(strLendRatePr); } catch { dblLRP = 0.0; }
            try { dblOPR = double.Parse(strOtherPr); } catch { dblOPR = 0.0; }

            try { intKeywordsSel = int.Parse(strKeywordsSelected); } catch { intKeywordsSel = 0; }

            try { intMarketandRevenueOptionsSel = int.Parse(strMarketandRevenueOptionsSelected); } catch { intMarketandRevenueOptionsSel = 0; }

            try { intKeywordsListSel = int.Parse(strKeywordsListSelected); } catch { intKeywordsListSel = 0; }
        

            //BW: For testing purpose add data to list 
            try
            {
                listIndustry.Add("Consumer Discretionary");
                listIndustry.Add("");

            }
            catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }

        

            try
            {
                strVD = strValDate.Split('-');
                dtVD = new DateTime(int.Parse(strVD[0].ToString()),
                    int.Parse(strVD[1].ToString()),
                    int.Parse(strVD[2].ToString()));
            }
            catch
            {
                //dtVD = new DateTime(2018, 12, 31);
                dtVD = DateTime.Now;
            }
        

            List<SelectListItem> tmpabc = new List<SelectListItem>();
            tmpabc.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "--Select Location--", Value = "2" });
            tmpabc.AddRange(webS.GetWaccOptionsOpLocations());
            resetValuesInListOfSelectListItem(tmpabc);
            objWACC.LocationList = tmpabc;

            List<SelectListItem> tmpbeta = new List<SelectListItem>();
            tmpbeta.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "--Select Beta--", Value = "2" });
            tmpbeta.AddRange(webS.GetWaccOptionsBeta());
            resetValuesInListOfSelectListItem(tmpbeta);
            objWACC.BetaList = tmpbeta;

            List<SelectListItem> tmpmrp = new List<SelectListItem>();
            tmpmrp.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "--Select Mrp--", Value = "3" });
            tmpmrp.AddRange(webS.GetWaccOptionsMRP());
            resetValuesInListOfSelectListItem(tmpmrp);
            objWACC.MrpList = tmpmrp;


            //BW: return a varible that have the values that user select or input from the UI
            objWACC.IndustrySelected = intIndSel;
            objWACC.LocationSelected = intLocSel;
            objWACC.FairValue = dblFV;
            objWACC.RiskFreeRate = dblRFR;
            objWACC.Beta = dblBeta;
            objWACC.Mrp = dblMRP;
            objWACC.CAPM = dblCAPM;
            objWACC.TaxRate = dblTAXRATE;
            objWACC.LendingRate = dblLendingRate;
            objWACC.WE = dblWE;
            objWACC.WD = dblWD;
            objWACC.AFTaxCod = dblAFTaxCod;
            objWACC.BetaSelected = intBetSel;
            objWACC.MrpSelected = intMrpSel;

            objWACC.SizePremium = dblSP;
            objWACC.ComSpecPr = dblCSP;
            objWACC.LendRatePr = dblLRP;
            objWACC.OtherPr = (objWACC.SizePremium + objWACC.ComSpecPr);

            objWACC.KeywordOptionsSelected = intKeywordsSel;
            objWACC.MarketandRevenueOptionsSelected = intMarketandRevenueOptionsSel;
            objWACC.KeywordsListSelected = intKeywordsListSel;

            string strOpLocation = objWACC.LocationList[intLocSel].Text;
            //string strIndustry = objWACC.IndustryList[intIndSel].Text;
            string strIndustry = "";

            string strBeta = objWACC.BetaList[intBetSel].Text;
            string strMRP = objWACC.MrpList[intMrpSel].Text;           

            string strIndustrylevel = objWACC.Industries.ToString();


            if (strBeta == "Beta WIND" || strBeta == "Beta BDO")
            {

                //BW: need to add string Industry level to webservice. 
                XmlDocument xmlWACCSummary = webS.GetWaccSummary(strOpLocation, strIndustry, strValDate, strMRP, strBeta, dblSP / 100, dblCSP / 100, dblLRP / 100);

                //BW: Below is a temp solution to check if the returned xml is a valid WACC summary
                XmlNodeList nodeWACCTmp = xmlWACCSummary.GetElementsByTagName("Relevered_Beta");
                if (nodeWACCTmp[0] == null)
                {
                    return View(objWACC);
                }

                nodeWACCTmp = xmlWACCSummary.GetElementsByTagName("Relevered_Beta");
                objWACC.Beta = Convert.ToDouble(nodeWACCTmp[0].LastChild.InnerText);

                nodeWACCTmp = xmlWACCSummary.GetElementsByTagName("WE");
                objWACC.WE = Convert.ToDouble(nodeWACCTmp[0].LastChild.InnerText);

                nodeWACCTmp = xmlWACCSummary.GetElementsByTagName("WD");
                objWACC.WD = Convert.ToDouble(nodeWACCTmp[0].LastChild.InnerText);

                nodeWACCTmp = xmlWACCSummary.GetElementsByTagName("MRP");
                objWACC.Mrp = Convert.ToDouble(nodeWACCTmp[0].LastChild.InnerText);

                nodeWACCTmp = xmlWACCSummary.GetElementsByTagName("CAPM");
                objWACC.CAPM = Convert.ToDouble(nodeWACCTmp[0].LastChild.InnerText);

                nodeWACCTmp = xmlWACCSummary.GetElementsByTagName("RFR");
                objWACC.RiskFreeRate = Convert.ToDouble(nodeWACCTmp[0].LastChild.InnerText);

                nodeWACCTmp = xmlWACCSummary.GetElementsByTagName("Tax_Rate");
                objWACC.TaxRate = Convert.ToDouble(nodeWACCTmp[0].LastChild.InnerText);

                nodeWACCTmp = xmlWACCSummary.GetElementsByTagName("Lending_Rate");
                objWACC.LendingRate = Convert.ToDouble(nodeWACCTmp[0].LastChild.InnerText);

                nodeWACCTmp = xmlWACCSummary.GetElementsByTagName("COD");
                objWACC.AFTaxCod = Convert.ToDouble(nodeWACCTmp[0].LastChild.InnerText);

                nodeWACCTmp = xmlWACCSummary.GetElementsByTagName("Other_Premium");
                objWACC.OtherPr = Convert.ToDouble(nodeWACCTmp[0].LastChild.InnerText);

          
                nodeWACCTmp = xmlWACCSummary.GetElementsByTagName("Lending_Rate_Premium");
                objWACC.LendRatePr = 100 * Convert.ToDouble(nodeWACCTmp[0].LastChild.InnerText);

                nodeWACCTmp = xmlWACCSummary.GetElementsByTagName("WACC");
                objWACC.FairValue = Convert.ToDouble(nodeWACCTmp[0].LastChild.InnerText);
            }
            return View(objWACC);
        }
```

Here is the View:

```
<div class="content" style="width:1000px">
            <p><input id="text_tag_input" class="form-control input-sm" type="text"></p>
            <br />      
            <div>
                    <table id="tbl_posts">
                        <tbody id="tbl_posts_body">
                            <tr id="rec-1">

                                @*BW: These is the dummy data for the keywords selection, when the sql is ready to linked to the model. These will be  deleted*@
                                @{
                                    Model.KeywordOptions = new List<SelectListItem>();

                                    Model.KeywordOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = "--Select Option--",
                                        Value = "selectoption1",
                                    });

                                    Model.KeywordOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = "Market Cap".ToString(),
                                        Value = "TEST 1",
                                    });
                                    Model.KeywordOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = "Revenue",
                                        Value = "TEST 2"
                                    });
                                    Model.KeywordOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = "Keywords",
                                        Value = "TEST 3"
                                    });
                                }

                                @{
                                    Model.MarketandRevenueOptions = new List<SelectListItem>();

                                    Model.MarketandRevenueOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = "--Select Option--",
                                        Value = "",
                                    });

                                    Model.MarketandRevenueOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = "Greater Than",
                                        Value = "Test 4",
                                    });
                                    Model.MarketandRevenueOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = "Less Than",
                                        Value = "Test 5"
                                    });

                                    Model.MarketandRevenueOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = "Equals",
                                        Value = "Test 6"
                                    });

                                    Model.MarketandRevenueOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = "Range",
                                        Value = "Test 7"
                                    });
                                }

                                @{
                                    Model.KeywordsList = new List<SelectListItem>();

                                    Model.KeywordsList.Add(new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = "--Select Option--",
                                        Value = "Test 8",
                                    });

                                    Model.KeywordsList.Add(new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = "Excluding",
                                        Value = "Test 9",
                                    });
                                    Model.KeywordsList.Add(new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = "Including",
                                        Value = "Test 10"
                                    });

                                    Model.KeywordsList.Add(new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = "Exact Phrase",
                                        Value = "Test 11"
                                    });

                                }

                                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.KeywordOptionsSelected, Model.KeywordOptions, new { @id = "Dropdown_TEST" })</td>

                                <td class="display" style="display:none; text-align:left; width:18px;">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MarketandRevenueOptionsSelected, Model.MarketandRevenueOptions, new { @id = "platt" })</td>


                                <td class="display_1" style="display:none; text-align:left; width:18px;">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.KeywordsListSelected, Model.KeywordsList, new { @id = "platt2" })</td>


                                <td class="display_2" style="display:none; text-align:center;">
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="number" name="keywordtextbox" value="0">
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td class="display_3" style="display:none; text-align:left;">
                                    <div style="text-align:center;">
                                        <input type="text" name="keywordtextbox" placeholder="e.g Toy Manufacturing">
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td><a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>


                    <div style="display:none;">

                        <table id="sample_table">
                            <tr id="">
                                <td>
                                    <select required id="Dropdown_clone">
                                        <option value="selectoption_clone">--Select Option--</option>
                                        <option class="cont" value="clone 1"> Market Cap</option>
                                        <option class="cont_1" value="clone 2"> Revenue</option>
                                        <option class="cont_2" value="clone 3"> Keywords</option>

                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td class="display_clone" style="display:none;">
                                    <select required id="platt_clone">
                                        <option value="">--Select Option--</option>
                                        <option value="clone 4"> Greater Than </option>
                                        <option value="clone 5"> Less Than </option>
                                        <option value="clone 6"> Equals </option>
                                        <option value="clone 7"> Range </option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td class="display_1_clone" style="display:none; text-align:left; width:10px">
                                    <select required id="platt2_clone">
                                        <option value="clone 8">--Select Option--</option>
                                        <option value="clone 9">Excluding</option>
                                        <option value="clone 10">Including</option>
                                        <option value="clone 11">Exact Phrase</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td class="display_2_clone" style="display:none;">
                                    <div style="text-align:right;">
                                        <input type="number" name="keywordtextbox" value="0">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="display_3_clone" style="display:none;">
                                    <div style="text-align:center;">
                                        <input type="text" name="keywordtextbox" placeholder="e.g Toy Manufacturing">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td><a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="0"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>


                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right add-record" data-added="0"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Row</a>
                    </div>

                <br />
                <br />
                <form>
                    <input type="submit" class="waccbuttonsubmit" value='Apply' />   
                    </form>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below technique in which populate your SelectList from your controller. Its simple and clean:

**Model**

```
public string KeywordOptionsSelected { get; set; }
public SelectList KeywordOptions { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
model.KeywordOptions = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> { 
                        new SelectListItem { Value = "TEST 1", Text = "Market Cap" },
                        new SelectListItem { Value = "TEST 2", Text = "Revenue" },
                        }, "Value", "Text");
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.KeywordOptionsSelected, Model.KeywordOptions, "--Select Option--", new { @id = "Dropdown_TEST" })
```

In this way, the code is easy to understand and View is also clean as all SelectList will be populated from cs.

You can make it more cleaner by populating SelectLists separately in methods and call in `model.KeywordOptions` to populate it.

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetKeywords()
{
    var keyword = new List<SelectListItem>();
    keyword.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "TEST 1", Text = "Market Cap" });
    keyword.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "TEST 2", Text = "Revenue" });
    return keyword;
}
model.KeywordOptions = new SelectList(GetKeywords(), "Value", "Text");
```

Comment: Thank You so much, it does help me organize better on my code!!!

Comment: My pleasure @SushiDesu that it solved your problem. Upvote the answer as well.

Comment: Always upvote the answer to whom you got the help. Its oxygen for the contributors.