# ASP.NET MVC 5 RegisterView - how to implement a Dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Want to implement a dropdown list on RegisterView cant figure out how to do it I'm new to asp.net mvc5 and following code first approach . I already have a table for Offices. I will list down all my coding. I think ( I'm not sure) i have to initialize the list but dont know how to do it and where to put it

Have a model Office.Cs

```
    public class Office
    {
        public byte Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Identity Model

```
        public IEnumerable<Office> Office { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public byte OfficeId { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

AccountViewModel.cs

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        public OfficeViewModel OfficeViewModel { get; set; }
                     
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Office")]
        public byte OfficeId { get; set; }
```

AccountController.cs

```
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                
                
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, OfficeId= model.OfficeId};
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                    
                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                    
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
```

RegisterView.cshtml

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OfficeId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OfficeId, new SelectList(Model.Office, "Id", "Name"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Controller

```
List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
// add you data to the list
var query = from of in your_context.Office
            select new SelectListItem()
            {
                  Text = of.Name,
                  Value = of.Id
            };
li = query.ToList();
ViewBag.Office = li;
```

in the View

```
<div class="col-md-10">
   @Html.DropDownList("Office", ViewBag.Office as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate the data in `SelectList` type field which should be declare in ViewModel class. This field of `SelectList` type collection would be use in `View` to bind with Dropdown list.

It is explained in my answer of another post:
[MVC C# Dropdown list Showing System.Web.SelectListItem on the model and can not blind to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63107963/mvc-c-sharp-dropdown-list-showing-system-web-selectlistitem-on-the-model-and-can/63113720#63113720)